# Sorry for/Sorry about in similar constructions

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Sorry **about** trying to get there on time, he said sarcastically.

Sorry **for** trying to get there on time, he said sarcastically.

Is using **about** in constructions where you're offering more details than just saying "Sorry about that" wrong? Basically, is the first sentence grammatically wrong? If I said "Sorry about walking into your room like that," would that be grammatically wrong? Lastly, do both the provided sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: It's not _grammatically_ wrong, but doesn't make sense; surely he would be sorry about **not** getting there on time despite having tried to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are sorry *for* something, you are accepting responsibility.

> I'm sorry for hurting your feelings.

When you are sorry *about* something, you are simply expressing sympathy.

> I'm sorry about your father's death.

If you said "I'm sorry *for* your father's death" it would sound like you'd killed him! Having said that, there may be a few idiomatic exceptions. For example, people do say "I'm sorry *for* your loss" in connection with bereavement.

Comment: I think you can be sorry _about_ an error or faux pas you have made.